# Is there a way to expose a static XSD in Spring WS 2?

Tags: java, spring, xsd, wsdl, spring-ws

If, for example orders.wsdl imports Orders.xsd, how can it be configured using static-wsdl

```
<sws:static-wsdl id="orders" location="/WEB-INF/wsdl/orders.wsdl"/>
```

such that Orders.xsd can be viewed in the browser like `http://host/context/Orders.xsd`

Dynamic wsdl supports it.

```
<sws:dynamic-wsdl id="orders"
    portTypeName="Orders"
    locationUri="http://localhost:8080/ordersService/">
  <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/xsd/Orders.xsd"/>
</sws:dynamic-wsdl>
```

But static-wsdl doesn't have the sws:xsd property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no namspace support but you can do this -

```
<bean id="Orders" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
    <property name="xsd" value="classpath:/Orders.xsd" />
</bean>
```

This will resolve the referenced xsd in your wsdl file -

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified">
        <xsd:import namespace="..." schemaLocation="Orders.xsd"></xsd:import>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

Comment: This is what I was doing in spring-ws 1.5. Looks like we are stuck with this somewhat cluttered approach. Spring recommends using static wsdl yet they can't add 'sws:xsd location' for imported xsd. beats me.

Answer (score 0):

or you can tyt with that

```
 <wsdl:types>


   <xs:schema targetNamespace="...."
          elementFormDefault="qualified">

                <xs:include schemaLocation="xsd/Order.xsd"/>

   </xs:schema>
```

Comment: You should supply some detail on how this code solves the problem. I found this answer through the "Low Quality Posts" list, so it's in danger of deletion.