# Spring WS Exposing XSD isn't working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-ws

I've followed the answer in this post to expose the xsd in my application - [Is there a way to expose a static XSD in Spring WS 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642100/is-there-a-way-to-expose-a-static-xsd-in-spring-ws-2)

my web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/springws-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.wsdl</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/airlinemvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>

    </servlet-mapping>
```

springws-servlet.xml

```
    <sws:annotation-driven />


    <sws:static-wsdl id="airline" location="/WEB-INF/wsdl/airlineservice.wsdl"/>

    <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="airlineWS" 
                        portTypeName="AirlineServicePortType" 
                        locationUri="http://localhost:8080/airline/services/"
                        createSoap11Binding="true"
                        createSoap12Binding="true" >
        <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/schemas/AirlineService.xsd"/>

    </sws:dynamic-wsdl>

    <bean id="AirlineTypes" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
        <property name="xsd" value="/WEB-INF/schemas/AirlineTypes.xsd"/>
    </bean>

   <bean id="AirlineService" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
        <property name="xsd" value="/WEB-INF/schemas/AirlineService.xsd"/>
    </bean>
```

Now I want to access AirlineService.xsd from the browser. I tried going to http://localhost:8080/airline/AirlineService.xsd and http://localhost:8080/airline/services/AirlineService.xsd - both of them are returning 404. What mistake am I making? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you dont put them outside of the WEB-INF folder and reach them via http://localhost:8080/airline/schemas/AirlineService.xsd

Comment: @Koitoer that will most likely work but it's really bugging me why my code isn't working. I just copied the sample as it is but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it our. MessageDispatcherServlet isn't able to handle requests for .xsd because there is no servlet-mapping declaration in web.xml for that.

two ways to fix it..

Method 1: Update the URL pattern to include everything under /services/

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Method 2:

Add another mapping

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>.xsd</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

As posted on:

http://www.mytechtip.com/2012/09/static-wsdl-with-imported-xml-schema-in.html

you should use:

```
`<bean 
    id="temperature-schema"
    class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
    <property 
        name="xsd" 
        value="/WEB-INF/wsdl/temperature-schema.xsd">
    </property>
</bean>`
```

where the id matches the name of the file containing your schema.